# A mathematical definition of quasi-particle based on second quantization

Tags: second-quantization, quasiparticles

Is there a mathematical definition of a quasi-particle? So far, from what I see in textbooks, a quasi-particle is that created by the creation operator $d^*$ which was obtained by a Bogoliubov transform from the annihilation/creation operators $c,c^*$ of real particles, e.g., electrons. Is this what we usually mean by quasi-particles?